# Recursive iteration over type lists and concatenation into a result type list

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20

Consider a scenario having various classes/structs, some having complex data members, which can contain more of them itself. In order to setup / initialize, a list of all dependencies is required before instantiantion.

Because the types are known before instantiation, my approach is to define a type list containing involved/relevant types in each class/struct like this:

```
template<typename...> struct type_list {};

struct a {
    using dependencies = type_list<>;
};

struct b {
    using dependencies = type_list<>;
};

struct c {
    using dependencies = type_list<b>;
    b b_;
};

struct d {
    using dependencies = type_list<a>;
    a a_;
};

struct e {
    using dependencies = type_list<c, a>;
    c c_;
    a a_;
    x x_; // excluded
};

struct f {
    using dependencies = type_list<a,b>;
    a a_;
    b b_;
    y y_; // excluded
};
```

For example I want to pre-initialize `d, e, f`.

The next steps are:

- iterate through the `dependencies` of `d,e,f` and concat each item to a result list
- recursively iterate through each element of every `dependencies[n]::dependencies` and concat each item to a result list and do the same for each type until type list is empty

The result may contain duplicates. These get reduced and sorted in a later step. I intend to do this using a constexpr hash map using hashes of `__FUNCSIG__ / __PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (not part of this).

How can this (iterating, accessing type list elements, concat into result list) be achieved using C++20 metaprogramming?

Comment: "*I want to pre-initialize `d`, `e`, `f`.*" What do you mean by that? `d`, `e` and `f` are *types*. You cannot "initialize" a type; you can only initialize an *object* of a type. So, are you trying to initialize 3 objects of those types? If so, where and how?

Comment: You can write a default constructor for each of the `struct`s that need initialization. Then the compiler will automatically construct/initialize the members (aka dependencies) recursively for you. I don't think you need type lists here.

Comment: @NicolBolas Initialization is done on remote device(s) using another architecture. For example memory needs to be allocated, triggered by host to make many instances fit aligned. To do so, some information is required upfront.

Comment: @JakobStark The minimal example I shared is very simplified. Remote devices receive partitions and will not know about local allocations on host device. Members will be pointers and/or ref's, or refs to ptr to device local instance pool. There will be a lot of instances, which would imply a lot of runtime overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just look at the metaprogramming part. As always, the solution is to use Boost.Mp11. In this case, it's one of the more involved algorithms: [`mp_iterate`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_iteratev_f_r).

This applies a function to a value until failure - that's how we can achieve recursion. We need several steps.

First, a metafunction to get the dependencies for a single type

```cpp
template <typename T> using dependencies_of = typename T::dependencies;
```

Then, we need a way to get all the dependencies for a list of types. Importantly, this needs to fail at some point (for `mp_iterate`'s stopping condition), so we force a failure on an empty list:

```cpp
template <typename L>
using list_dependencies_of = std::enable_if_t<
    not mp_empty<L>::value,
    mp_flatten<mp_transform<dependencies_of, L>>>;
```

And then we can iterate using those pieces:

```cpp
template <typename L>
using recursive_dependencies_of = mp_unique<mp_apply<mp_append,
    mp_iterate<
        L,
        mp_identity_t,
        list_dependencies_of
        >>>;
```

The `mp_append` concatenates the list of lists that `mp_iterate` gives you, and then `mp_unique` on top of that since you don't want to have duplicates.

This takes a list, so can be used like `recursive_dependencies_of<mp_list<a>>` (which is just `mp_list<a>`) or `recursive_dependencies_of<mp_list<d, e, f>>` (which is `mp_list<d, e, f, a, c, b>`).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8ob79soEW).

Comment: Thanks for this clean and really simple appearing solution. Honestly I hoped to avoid Boost to reduce dependencies (and for learning), but I see the benefit of efficiency doing it that way including consumption of expert optimized and maintained solutions.